# MongoDB won't save JSON document?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongojs, nosql

Quick question, but does anyone have a clue why MongoDB won't save the following document? I'm using MongoJS in NodeJS to connect to MongoDB and using the following lines of code to save (in my JS file, the function call is underneath the variable definition). The save function doesn't save, but automatically goes to the callback function.

Any thoughts? Thanks so much :).

---

Edit:
After adding an error log to the callback, I'm getting the following error:

```
{ [MongoError: error parsing element 0 of field documents :: caused by :: wrong type for '0' field, expected object, found 0: "{"Word":"Count","read":1,"letter":1,"wh":1,"urging":2,"swift":1,"approval":1,"add'l":1,"lease":1,"space":1,"fayetteville":1,"vamc":1,"vets":2,"care":1..."]
  name: 'MongoError',
  ok: 0,
  errmsg: 'error parsing element 0 of field documents :: caused by :: wrong type for \'0\' field, expected object, found 0: "{"Word":"Count","read":1,"letter":1,"wh":1,"urging":2,"swift":1,"approval":1,"add\'l":1,"lease":1,"space":1,"fayetteville":1,"vamc":1,"vets":2,"care":1..."',
  code: 9 }
```

---

```
db.collection.save(json_buffer, function() {
    console.log("Complete");
});

  var json_buffer = {"Word":"Count","read":1,"letter":1,"wh":1,"urging":2,"swift":1,"approval":1,"add'l":1,"lease":1,"space":1,"fayetteville":1,"vamc":1,"vets":2,"care":1,"@gnip":3,"--":3,"delivering":3,"data":3,"happy":3,"customers":3,"outrageous":1,"france":1,"sell":1,"warships":1,"putin":1,"@senatorkirk":1,"@repkinzinger":1,"@usrepkeating":1,"&amp":5,"urge":1,"strong":1,"action":3,"polling":1,"shows":1,"race":1,"close":1,"pitch":1,"pre-primary":1,"deadline":1,"goal":2,"joining":1,"@teamcavuto":1,"shortly":1,"discuss":1,"can’t":1,"continue":1,"punt":1,"debt":2,"crisis":1,"road":1,"watch":1,"opening":1,"remarks":1,"today’s":1,"senate":1,"committee":1,"hearing":1,"mcdonald":1,"nomination":1,"urged":1,"passage":1,"#summermealsact":2,"yesterday":1,"#monticello":1,"#ny--so":1,"impt":1,"expand":1,"@usda's":1,"summer":2,"nutrition":1,"program":1,"great":2,"catch":1,"high":1,"school":2,"friend":1,"john":1,"choate":1,"today":7,"family":1,"capitol":1,"hill":1,"child":1,"america":1,"wake":1,"day":1,"wondering":1,"eat":1,"nebraska":1,"communities":1,"access":1,"local":1,"tv":1,"programming":1,"introduced":1,"bill":4,"work":2,"past":1,"time":2,"congress":1,"meaningful":1,"reduce":1,"threat":1,"cyber":1,"attacks":1,"@mercnews":1,"op-ed":1,"fitting":1,"@us_sfrc":1,"passed":1,"#crpd":1,"bob":1,"dole's":1,"bday":1,"#disabilitytreaty":1,"advocate":1,"beginning":1,"#isupportcrpd":1,"senator":1,"mcconnell":2,"co-sponsors":1,"protect":2,"correctional":1,"officers":2,"daily":1,"independent":2,"#ashland":1,"#kentucky":1,"millions":1,"children":2,"recv":1,"free":1,"reduced":1,"meals":1,"year":1,"left":1,"hungry":1,"months":1,"unacceptable":1,"rt":5,"@aterkel":1,"record":1,"phone":1,"@senschumer":1,"…":1,"good":1,"meeting":1,"anne":1,"rung":1,"nominee":1,"@ombpress":1,"office":2,"fed":1,"procurement":1,"policy":1,"cc":1,"@senatehsgac":1,"@federalreserve":1,"divert":1,"leftover":1,"funds":1,"foreclosure":1,"review":1,"hardest":1,"hit":1,"fund":1,"#ri":1,"supports":1,"corrections":1,"prisons":1,"manchester":1,"pine":1,"knot":1,"ashland":1,"inez":1,"lex":1,"miami":1,"valley":1,"well-run":1,"base":1,"makes":1,"wright-patt":1,"#1":1,"airmen":1,"@gopoversight":1,"release":1,"#irs":2,"needed":1,"days":1,"confirm":1,"lerner":1,"hard":2,"drive":1,"crash":2,"provide":1,"support":3,"runaway":1,"homeless":1,"youth":1,"victims":1,"trafficking":1,"@housefloor":1,"tomorrow":1,"glad":1,"signature":1,"industry":1,"@kydistillers":1,"@repandybarr":1,"obama":1,"meant":1,"flexibility":1,"re-elected":1,"thoughts":1,"prayers":1,"affected":1,"fires":1,"tooele":1,"pray":1,"staying":1,"safe":1,"#utpol":1,"hr":1,"passes":1,"house":1,"@repderekkilmer":1,"modernize":1,"labs":1,"fyi":1,"fun":1,"activities":1,"hosted":1,"google":1,"young":1,"inventors":1,"age":1,"13+":1,"choose":1,"projects":1,"virtual":1,"field":1,"trips":1,"joined":1,"nyc":1,"workforce":2,"development":2,"hosting":1,"roundtable":1,"#bronx":1,"failure":1,"disclose":1,"timely":1,"manner":1,"destroyed":1,"critical":1,"evidence":1,"reason":2,"special":1,"prosecutor":1,"26%":1,"texas":1,"live":1,"poverty":1,"#raisethewage":1,"#honorflightact":2,"codify":1,"process":1,"tsa":1,"expedited":1,"dignified":1,"screening":1,"veterans":1,"visiting":1,"war":1,"memorials":1,"humbled":1,"join":2,"medal":1,"honor":1,"recipient":1,"staff":1,"sergeant":1,"ryan":1,"pitts":1,"nashua":1,"ceremony":1,"pentagon":1,"icymi":1,"statement":1,"halbig":1,"burwell":1,"@ecpzachevans":1,"save":1,"date":1,"mt":1,"@shrinersfest":1,"dates":1,"announced":1,"shrinersfest":1,"june":1,"25-28":1,"feat":1,"@blueangels":1,"htt…":1,"unleash":1,"america's":1,"energy":2,"abundance":1,"create":1,"#jobs":1,"economic":1,"growth":1,"affordable":1,"#yes2energy":1,"marks":1,"#100days":1,"nigerian":1,"schoolgirls":1,"kidnapping":1,"forgotten":1,"#bringbackourgirls":1,"pleased":1,"mayor":1,"@rahmemanuel":1,"taking":1,"@fly2ohare":1,"noise":1,"measure":1,"seeks":1,"pay":1,"gratitude":1,"group":1,"americans":1,"make":1,"ultimate":1,"sacrifice":1,"stopped":1,"dutch":1,"embassy":1,"offer":1,"condolences":1,"lost":1,"loved":1,"#mh17":1,"#obamafailures":1,"min":1,"#131":1,"odds":1,"drives":1,"irs":1,"claims":1,"win":1,"fl":1,"lottery":1,"times":1,"#tcot":1}
```

Comment: add an error arg to the callback and log it

Comment: I'm getting the following error:

`
{ [MongoError: error parsing element 0 of field documents :: caused by :: wrong type for '0' field, expected object, found 0: "{"Word":"Count","read":1,"letter":1,"wh":1,"urging":2,"swift":1,"approval":1,"add'l":1,"lease":1,"space":1,"fayetteville":1,"vamc":1,"vets":2,"care":1..."]
  name: 'MongoError',
  ok: 0,
  errmsg: 'error parsing element 0 of field documents :: caused by :: wrong type for \'0\' field, expected object, found 0: "
`

Comment: Works fine in the mongo shell. Could you post a minimal code example to trigger this exception?

Comment: Please try to remove fields from that huge document until you identified the exact field which causes the problem (I would start with those which contain non-alphanumeric characters).

Answer (score 6):

Struggled with this for a long time, despite reading up here. Actual cause of the issue finally turned out to be that the JSON object I was trying to update was 'undefined'. Try catching the mongo error and printing the entire error object.

The JSON object was being considered as undefined in my case because it was actually an array, not an object. So I tried doing a mongo update on myJsonObject[0] rather than myJsonObject which was actually an array, and this succeeded.

Do a console.log of the stringified json 'object' you are trying to save, and if it's surrounded by square braces, then you know you're dealing with an array, and need to work on its element(s) instead.

Answer (score 4):

I had this error when:

- Create JSON object in client code
- Send it over http request
- Get it from the request body in node code
- Send the body content to mongodb

The problem was the object sent was a String, not a JSON object...

Using `var json = JSON.parse(json-string-from-body)` and send `json` solve my problem.

Also, I used `insert()` method not `save()`. In mongodb console `save({"htt…":1})` which is a part of your data return an error but `insert({"htt…":1})` works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error with Mongoose when doing

```
Model.update(docId, {...})
```

when I should have been doing

```
Model.update({_id: docId}, {...})
```

Comment: Same. Thanks for sharing. I feel cheated that this shortcut isn't supported.